# __toString - what does it do in this class?

Tags: php, class

Most of the work I do is on a legacy app written procedurally.  I'm beginning to convert pieces of it to OOP, and came across this example class used to add multiple times together:

At the bottom of the class, there is a public function called `__toString()`, which appears to return some formatted text.

```
class Duration 
{
    /*
        $d1 = Duration::fromString('2:22');
        $d1->add(Duration::fromString('3:33'));
        echo $d1; // should print 5:55
    */
    public static function fromString($string)
    {
        $parts = explode(':', $string);
        $object = new self();
        if (count($parts) === 2) {
            $object->minutes = $parts[0];
            $object->seconds = $parts[1];
        } elseif (count($parts) === 3) {
            $object->hours = $parts[0];
            $object->minutes = $parts[1];
            $object->seconds = $parts[2];
        } else {
            // handle error
        }
        return $object;
    }

    private $hours;
    private $minutes;
    private $seconds;

    public function getHours() {
        return $this->hours;
    }

    public function getMinutes() {
        return $this->minutes;
    }

    public function getSeconds() {
        return $this->seconds;
    }

    public function add(Duration $d) {
        $this->hours += $d->hours;
        $this->minutes += $d->minutes;
        $this->seconds += $d->seconds;
        while ($this->seconds >= 60) {
            $this->seconds -= 60;
            $this->minutes++;
        }
        while ($this->minutes >= 60) {
            $this->minutes -= 60;
            $this->hours++;
        }
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return implode(':', array($this->hours, $this->minutes, $this->seconds));
    }

}
```

The public static function `fromString()` contains a return, and is how the class is called from a script.  How does this class use `__toString`?  Why isn't the implode simply included in `fromString()`?

Comment: First google hit gives me the proper resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the one makes Duration objects from strings, the other turns Duration objects into strings.

This will return an object of class Duration, made from string $string:

```
public static function fromString($string)  { ... store input string ... }
```

If you now want to output the original string, you can't just echo the Duration object itself, because it is not a string but a Duration object.

If you want to be able to echo a Duration object, you implement the `__toString()` function:

```
public function __toString() { ... build and return output string ... }
```

And then you can do stuff like this:

```
$stringOne = 'Some string';
$durationObject = Duration::fromString($stringOne);
echo $durationObject; // Echo-ing the object works because __toString is implemented.
```

The third line in that code won't work if you don't implement the __toString() method.

Comment: So __toString() is called automatically, because it is "magic"..  and thus, it was not extraneous after all?

Comment: Confirmed behaviour.   When I commented out that function, I get no output from the third line.  thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Straight from the [**documentation**<sup>PHP.net</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring):

> The *`__toString()`* method allows a class to decide how it will react
>   when it is treated like a string. For example, what *`echo $obj;`* will
>   print. This method must return a string, as otherwise a fatal
>   *`E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR`* level error is emitted.

The class itself doesn't use `__toString()`, it's only mentioned implicitly in the usage suggestion in the comment: `echo $d1; // should print 5:55`

Whenever you treat an object as a string, PHP will replace `$obj` with `$obj.__toString()` for you.

This happens when:

- `echo`-ing
- using `printf` with `%s`
- casting to string: (string) $obj
- concatenating with `.`

This isn't an exhaustive list of course. If you treat an object as a string that ***doesn't*** have a `__toString` method, you get:

```
Catchable fatal error:  Object of class * could not be converted to string in
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that red box on the doc page.  Why do I need my class to decide how to react?   In the example provided, a string is always returned - so why add the extra `__toString` code?

Comment: You are editing your question in response to my comments.  Why would someone add the extra code `__toString` (from the OP example) if it is not being used?

Comment: It is said in the comments at the beginning: `echo $d1; // should print 5:55` and that is the whole purpose of it. If you don't intend to use something like this, then the extra code (since not being used) makes no sense, just like you said

Comment: Ok - that is what was confusing me.  It was extraneous.  Wish folks weren't so downvote happy - I did read the php docs, just didn't fully understand them in the context of the OP example.

Comment: @acoder When you read the documentation and don't understand something, you can ask a question about *exactly that*, quoting what you don't understand.

Comment: Commenting out the `toString()` function results in no output being produced.  So when you say "the class itself doesn't use __toString()" it further confused this.

Comment: @acoder You asked `How does this class use __toString?` Since the class doesnt' use it, it's correct. Why this confuses you, why the truth confuses you, I can't say ;)

Comment: The class does use `__toString()`.   When that function is commented out, I get no output.   Are you sure you understand this?

Comment: @acoder Yes I do ;) It's not the class that uses it, it's *you*. When you write `echo $d1;`, the `__toString()` method is being used. The class *itself* however, doesn't do that. That means: No method in the class (fromString, getHours, getSeconds, add etc) uses `__toString()` in any way. Whenever you treat an *object* as a string (printing, concatenating, printf with %s), PHP will call `__toString()` on it and use that as the value. Does that clear things up?

Comment: But PHP doesn't call __toString automatically, right?  Here's an example with __toString commented out.  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7k2-nfa

Comment: @acoder Yes, it does call `__toString` automatically whenever you treat an object as a string. If it doesn't have that method, you will get an error provided you show the errors. [**See here**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c9d60aeb707c06d7bb8d406f05886dac10298059) for the error produced from your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29508/discussion-between-a-coder-and-phant0m)

Answer (score 0):

It is a magic method as you can read in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring). Example #2:

```
<?php
// Declare a simple class
class TestClass
{
    public $foo;

    public function __construct($foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}

$class = new TestClass('Hello');
echo $class; // Hello
```

Comment: Sure - I read that before posting.  Why not simply add return `$this=>foo` in `__construct`?   Why is the extra step needed?  I apologize if this sounds like a super ignorant question, but I don't regularly work in OOP.  Appreciate your patience.

Comment: @acoder You cannot use `return` in a constructor. --- What's with the -1?